# How can I extricate ginger minced in my blender to use it, without anything touching its blades?

Tags: kitchen

To save time and eschew knifes, my grandparents dropped whole  garlic cloves and ginger roots into their Vitamix blender to mince. It worked, but some smidgens are trapped under the blades. They fancy using these smidgens.

They mustn't use anything that can touch, and thus scratch or blemish, the blades. They  tried to turn the blender jar upside down to shake them out, but they remained stuck to the bottom.

I'm not asking about ridding these smidgens  which is easy; they just flush them out with water.

[image]

Comment: Is the goal to use the mush under the blades or to clean the blender?

Comment: @Stephie Thanks for clarifying! 'use the mush under the blades'.

Comment: Your desirable requirement for a method "without anything touching its blades" is rather unrealistic. Even the manufacturer **recommends** using a rubber spatula or scraper in its owner's manual to remove "smidgens."

Comment: Not an answer, but I would suggest grating it instead using the "zesting" side of the grater. This also avoids you needing to peel the garlic and ginger!

Answer (score 5):

The bottom of the blender where the blades are, unscrews. Simply unscrew it, separate the rubber washer, the blades from the screw-on base, and wash carefully with dish soap and a toothbrush to get the small bits. Dry all parts before reassembling.

As for retrieving the minced product, unscrew the bottom, remove blades and use a small rubber spatula or fork.

[image: washing the blender]

Answer (score 1):

If there are liquid ingredients also used in the same recipe, they can be added to the Vitamix® glass container to rinse the garlic and ginger free from the blades and poured out into a bowl or other dish for the other ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of Stan's answer, I would say to put a small amount of clean water in the blender and activate it, then pour the resulting liquid into a strainer to retrieve the "smidgens".

If the complaint would then become that they will lose flavour, pour the water plus bits into the recipe.

If the complaint would then become that the recipe doesn't call for water (and per stan's suggestion no other liquid will suffice either) you could either evaporate it away or plain up  forget about the smidgens (which by definition is a very small amount) and wash them down the drain, taking some solace in having fed the fish/worms.

If you know that the blender routinely traps on average X grams/fractions of an ounce of smidgens, add that weight extra when starting the blend to account for wastage. Consider also blending a larger amount of ingredient in a single batch and then using it over the course of s few recipes having incurred only one wastage. This option exists commercially too, with pre-blended, jarred ingredients such as garlic and ginger being available under names like "easy garlic"

Bear in mind that we are talking about ingredients worth perhaps fractions of a cent that will never repay the minimum wage cost of the time invested in recovering them. There are certainly many other avenues of money saving or waste reduction one could look to pursue that would deliver better value living

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

Probably the remainder of ingredients that your grandparents can't easily recover using a spatula should be ignored and discarded.

The Why:

Vita-Mix™ Corporation makes a series of expensive, high-quality models of machines which come with a choice of two blades specifically for wet (marked W) or dry (marked D) ingredients. Dry blades for grains can make flour.

The wet blade is standard and is appropriate for most things. Your grandparents are most probably using the wet blade.

**UNLIKE** other brands, Osterizer®, Sunbeam®, etc. the Vitamix® machine blades **do not need to be removed for cleaning** so disassembling the extremely sharp blades from the base is not a casual effort. It probably should be discouraged to get whatever stuff remains in the blades.

According to the Vitamix® machine Owner's Manual IMPORTANT SAFEGUARDS (page 4, #12) … A rubber scraper or spatula may be used, but only when the Vitamix blender is not running.

**NOTE:** A rubber scraper/spatula is the *only* kitchen utensil mentioned in the whole series of owner/instruction manuals provided by the manufacturer.

BTW; If the original has been misplaced, all of the manuals available for each model can be found and downloaded as PDFs from the [manufacturer's website](https://www.vitamix.com/us/en_us/owners-resources/product-support/owners-manuals).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointed wooden skewer.  Remove the blades to more easily poke into the underneath part of it.

Or, more simply, buy your grandparents another $1 head of garlic so that you can clean the blades without spending hoirs extracting less then 1g of substance, and tell your grandparents to be more decent generally.